# org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data

Tags: java, maven, jersey, multipartform-data, jersey-client

I am writing Client-side code in the Jersey framework where I need to send a YAML file that will have configuration details. I am continuously having exception

> MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=multipart/form-data.

I am not sure where the exact issue lies. Here is the snippet of my code. In the headerParam, I am having auth token which I need to submit.

```java
Invocation.Builder invocationBuilder =  null;
WebTarget target = _client.target(url);
invocationBuilder = target.request(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE);
if(headerParam.size()!=0){
    MultivaluedMap<String, Object> multivaluedMap = new MultivaluedHashMap<>(headerParam);
    invocationBuilder.headers(multivaluedMap);
}
MultiPart multiPart = new MultiPart();
log.info(methodName+"Hello");
FileDataBodyPart fileDataBodypart = new FileDataBodyPart("file",new File(path));
multiPart.bodyPart(fileDataBodypart);
    
Response response = invocationBuilder.post(Entity.entity(multiPart,MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_TYPE ));
log.info(methodName+"so reponse is : "+response);
```

I have added pom dependency in pom file also.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
    <version>2.22</version>
</dependency>
```

Can someone help why this issue is coming. Is there an issue with versioning or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the multipart dependency, but you still need to register the `MultiPartFeature` with either the Client or the WebTarget

```java
_client.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
// or
target.register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

Comment: Thanks Paul. I was able to connect after registering the dependency